# Portugal Resident re-entering in Portugal after a trip to Brazil

Tags: europe, portugal, brazilian-citizens

I have a Portuguese Residence Authorization. I will travel to Brazil during 15 days.

When I will be back to Portugal (I will enter in Europe thru Lisbon), my resident card is enough to enter in?

Or should also I show all requirements? Travel health security, money and so on..

I am asking, bc my "Cartão de Utente" is not more valid. I have a private health plan paid by the company that I work, but it will renew in end of the year and maybe, I will not have this in my hand until my back trip (Jan 1st).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resident card and passport will be enough to enter Portugal on your way back, unless you are violating the rules by not having the proper insurances etc of course but it seems to me that you do have the insurance just not the actual paper for it?

Of course if you are breaking the rules and you do not in fact have the proper details in place, you might still get lucky and get in as further spot checks would random and not carried out routinely.

Just remember it is always a bad idea to break the rules and then travel because Murphy’s law states you will always be the one singled out for further scrutiny and then trouble starts.